# Why rbind and cbind produce same output with sapply

Tags: r, apply

With following list of lists:

```
> lll = list(list(5,3,4), list(5,3,7), list(6,2,1), list(6,1,3), list(5,2,1))
```

I expected output to be transposed with rbind and cbind with sapply, but they are identical:

```
> sapply(lll, rbind)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 5    5    6    6    5   
[2,] 3    3    2    1    2   
[3,] 4    7    1    3    1   
> sapply(lll, cbind)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 5    5    6    6    5   
[2,] 3    3    2    1    2   
[3,] 4    7    1    3    1   
> 
> identical(sapply(lll, cbind), sapply(lll, rbind))
[1] TRUE
```

Why is this so and what code will produce transposed output of cbind vs rbind?

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(lll, rbind))`?

Comment: and `do.call(cbind, lapply(lll, cbind))`.

Comment: Yes, these work. You might want to put that as an answer with some explanation.

Comment: @Abdou why lapply? `do.call(cbind, lll); do.call(rbind, lll)` ?

Comment: One might be deceived into thinking the `rbind` or `cbind` actually combined the lists, but that's just because the `sapply` basically does a `cbind` in this case.  The actual `rbind` or `cbind` in this example just converts the sublists to matrices, and `sapply` doesn't actually care that they're matrices.  Replace `rbind` with `identity` and you get the same output here.

Answer (score 6):

The way you wrote it, `rbind` is applied separately to each of your sublists, so it's not actually combining them with anything.  In this case, all it really does is add dimension attributes to the sublist, changing it from a list with `length=3` to a matrix with `dim=c(1,3)`.  `cbind` does the same except you'll get `dim=c(3,1)`.  The point is, as you wrote it neither `rbind` nor `cbind` is actually used to combine the sublists together.  This is all done by `sapply`, and `sapply` doesn't care about their dimensions as matrices.  It treats them as vectors and combines them as columns.

Consider this somewhat simpler example:

```
> sapply(list(list(1,2,3),list(4,5,6)),rbind)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1    4   
[2,] 2    5   
[3,] 3    6
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
> sapply(list(rbind(list(1,2,3)),rbind(list(4,5,6))),identity)
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
> sapply(list(matrix(list(1,2,3),c(1,3)),matrix(list(4,5,6),c(1,3))),identity)
```

which is equivalent to this, since `sapply` cares about their lengths but not their dimensions:

```
> sapply(list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)),identity)
```

which is basically just this (since `sapply` combines them as columns):

```
> cbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
```

What you really wanted was to call `rbind` once, with each of the sublists as arguments, not to call it separately on each of the sublists.  In other words, you wanted it to work like this:

```
> rbind(list(1,2,3),list(4,5,6))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

But since you already have the sublists stored in a single list, you can achieve this by using `do.call`, which lets you supply all the arguments of `rbind` as a single `list`:

```
> list_of_lists <- list(list(1,2,3),list(4,5,6))
> do.call(rbind, list_of_lists)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1    2    3   
[2,] 4    5    6
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `cbind` and `rbind` work for vectors. For example, see this:

```
v <- c(3,1,2)
cbind(v)
#     v
#[1,] 3
#[2,] 1
#[3,] 2

rbind(v)
#  [,1] [,2] [,3]
#v    3    1    2
```

But `sapply` has an argument named `simplify` which is `TRUE` by default and this argument neutralizes the effect of `rbind` and `cbind` in your code. `?sapply` for the argument `simplify` states that:

> logical or character string; should the result be simplified to a vector, matrix or higher dimensional array if possible?

Actually what your code does is the same as this code:

```
sapply(lll, function(x) x)
```

To make it work, I'd do (suggested already by others though):

```
x <- do.call(rbind, lll)

     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 5    3    4   
# [2,] 5    3    7   
# [3,] 6    2    1   
# [4,] 6    1    3   
# [5,] 5    2    1   

t(x)
     # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] 5    5    6    6    5   
# [2,] 3    3    2    1    2   
# [3,] 4    7    1    3    1
```

Or using `data.table` library:

```
x <- rbindlist(lll)
t(x)
```

Or

```
x <- matrix(unlist(lll), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
t(x)
```

Once we get the output of one form (e.g. `rbind`), we transpose the result to get the other form (to get it done for `cbind` case).

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired output, you may want to try using `do.call` and `lapply`:

`rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lll, rbind))
```

`cbind`:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(lll, cbind))
```

As pointed out by @zx8754, it is actually possible to skip the usage of `apply` and just use `do.call` to get it done (something I was not aware of, for lists inside of a list. Thanks!):

`cbind` and `rbind`:

```
do.call(cbind, lll)
do.call(rbind, lll)
```

Thanks!